# What's the difference between *uint and uintptr in Golang?

Tags: pointers, go

According to the [Golang tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/11), we're provided with the following integer types:

```
int  int8  int16  int32  int64
uint uint8 uint16 uint32 uint64 uintptr
```

In theory, that means we could also have pointers to all of these types as follows:

```
*int  *int8  *int16  *int32  *int64
*uint *uint8 *uint16 *uint32 *uint64 *uintptr
```

If this is the case, then we already have a pointer to a uint in the form of *uint.  That would make uintptr redundant.  The [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#uintptr) doesn't shed much light on this:

```
uintptr is an integer type that is large enough to hold the bit pattern of any pointer.
```

As I understand it, that means that the bit width of a uint is determined at compile time based on the target architecture (typically either 32-bit or 64-bit).  It seems logical that the pointer width should scale to the target architecture as well (IE: a 32-bit *uint points to a 32-bit uint).  Is that the case in Golang?

Another thought was that maybe uintptr was added to make the syntax less confusing when doing multiple indirection (IE: `foo *uinptr` vs `foo **uint`)?

My last thought is that perhaps pointers and integers are incompatible data types in Golang.  That would be pretty frustrating since the hardware itself doesn't make any distinction between them.  For instance, a "branch to this address" instruction can use the same data from the same register that was just used in an "add this value" instruction.

What's the real point (pun intended) of uintptr?

Comment: uintptr is basically an unsafe pointer to anything, unrelated to uint.

Comment: It seems I forgot about 32-bit code running on 64-bit systems.  In that case *uint would be 4 bytes and uintptr would be 8 bytes.  Indeed, it looks like they're unrelated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The short answer is "never use `uintptr`".

The long answer is that `uintptr` is there to bypass the type system and allow the Go implementors to write Go runtime libraries, including the garbage collection system, in Go, and to call C-callable code including system calls using C pointers that are not handled *by* Go at all.

If you're acting as an implementor—e.g., providing access to system calls on a new OS—you'll need `uintptr`.  You will also need to know all the special magic required to use it, such as locking your goroutine to an OS-level thread if the OS is going to do stack-ish things to OS-level threads, for instance.  (If you're using it with Go pointers, you may also need to tell the compiler not to move your goroutine stack, which is done with special compile-time directives.)

Edit: as [kostix notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042646/whats-the-difference-between-uint-and-uintptr-in-golang/59042719?noredirect=1#comment104329244_59042719), the runtime system considers an `unsafe.Pointer` as a reference to an object, which keeps the object alive for GC.  It *does not* consider a `uintptr` as such a reference.  (That is, while `unsafe.Pointer` has a pointer type, `uintptr` has integer type.)  See also the [documentation for the `unsafe` package](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/).

Comment: To make this good answer a bit less magical… — `uintptr` may contain any pointer value but — contrary to `unsafe.Pointer`s, the GC does not consider `uintptr`s as live references to the memory blocks they point to. That's why they cannot be used except in certain narrow controlled cases.

Answer (score 5):

uintptr is simply an integer representation of a memory address, regardless of the actual type it points to. Sort of like `void *` in C, or just casting a pointer to an integer. It's purpose is to be used in unsafe black magic, and it is not used in everyday go code.

Answer (score 4):

You are conflating uintptr and *uint. uintptr is used when you're dealing with pointers, it is a datatype that is large enough to hold a pointer. It is mainly used for unsafe memory access, look at the unsafe package. *uint is a pointer to an unsigned integer.

Comment: So in this [example](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/zsyscall_windows.go#L3050). `uintptr(session)` it seems like it's casting a value to a pointer, and the ptr is not _actually_ used as a pointer. Or does uintptr() internally get the pointer of the int?

Comment: `uintptr` is simply an integer large enough to hold a pointer. It is still an int. The syscall will interpret the pointer as a pointer.